# lxd/lxc adding storage pool fails with "outside mount path"

Tags: lxc, lxd

I have installed two additional NVMe 7TB SDD as RAID1 with btrfs
(having an already running btrfs RAID1 with 1.8TB in an existing storage pool containing 7 containers)

Adding the 7TB RAID1 as a storage pool fails:

```
lxc storage create pool7t btrfs source=/vm/pool7t
Error: Could not determine if existing btrfs subvolume is empty: "/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/vm/pool7t"
       is outside pool mount path "/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/pool7t"
```

I have no idea how to resolve this error.

Background info:

```
lxc --version
5.19

mkfs.btrfs -f -d raid1 /dev/nvme2n1 /dev/nvme3n1

mount /dev/nvme2n1 /mnt
btrfs subvolume create /mnt/@pool7t
umount /mnt

mkdir /vm/pool7t
nano /etc/fstab
  UUID="4c3a59de-baeb-4a15-b454-a24baaa9faaa" /vm/pool7t btrfs defaults,subvol=@pool7t 0 0
systemctl daemon-reload

# This is the HD I want to use as a storage pool
mount /vm/pool7t
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem. To solve it, I used `lxd recover` to import an existing storage pool, instead of creating a new one.